# React Native Axios Call Inside Function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I tried to put POST by AXIOS function inside another function to reuse it multiple times. but unfortunately It doesn't work as I expected (which was working using FETCH),

AXIOS CALL JS:

```
export async function post(apiRoute, body) {

    try {


        body = JSON.stringify(body);
        axios.post(apiRoute, body, httpOptions)
             .then((res)=>{
                console.log(res.data);                // I have data here
                return res.data;
             });
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
    }
}
```

And the caller is:

```
    async DoLogin(userName, password) {
        
        var data = await post(url,{     // post is axios method defined above in another file
            UserName: userName,
            Password: password
        });


        return data;                // I have nothing here
    }
```

And the problem is I got **undefined** in DoLogin but got data inside POST method, It seems the problem is related to timing, axions returns a promise which is not possible to read in DoLogin, how I can do this? I did this via FETCH and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using async-await in this way.

```
export async function post(apiRoute, body) {

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(apiRoute, body, httpOptions)
        return response.data; 
    }
    catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I use this as a function?   I have FETCH as this: export async function post(apiRoute, body) {  .....

Comment: Thanks Mohammad, I'm testing it